# How to Cast a generic type of any type to another type

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a recursive method that makes a deep copy of a dictionary to any length by checking if the hash value is another dictionary and then copy it again before hashing it.

I have tried this and the compiler rejects the line in Blockquote, who can find the error?

```
private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> NestedCopy<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, 
                                                         TValue> nestedDict)
{

    var retDict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    foreach (var dict in nestedDict)
    {
         if (dict.Value is Dictionary<Object, Object>)
         {
             retDict[dict.Key] = NestedCopy(dict.Value asDictionary<object, object>);
         }
     }
     return retDict;
}
```

> retDict[dict.Key] = NestedCopy(dict.Value asDictionary);
>
> This is the error line,
>
> It says it cannot implicitly convert from Dictionary to TValue

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> dict; 
var newDict = NestedCopy(newDict);
//I expect newDict to be a copy of dict
```

Comment: You’re missing a space after `as`?

Comment: Also, the inner `NestedCopy` call is *very unlikely* returning an object of `TValue` (since it’s not called with generic arguments), so you probably cannot do that assignment to `retDict`.

Comment: @poke, I have put the space there, still error

Comment: What is the exact error message? Also, can you show an example dictionary and how you would expect this method to be called? I’m pretty sure that this conceptually won’t work the way you likely would expect it to.

Comment: I thought the compiler would infer the types?

Comment: It can in some situations, but not inside this method where you have just the generic type `TValue`. Type inference happens at compile time. – Please show an example usage (edit the question).

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: @jerry raised a good point in his answer... you talk about deep copy, but what do you expect for `Dictionary<int, SomeClassType>`? Currently you would copy the reference to `SomeClassType`, making a deep copy of the dictionary structure but not of its content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for the compiler to statically infer the recursive call. So, you gonna need reflection or at least let the compiler do the reflection for you by using the `dynamic` keyword:

```
private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> NestedCopy<TKey, TValue>(
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue> nestedDict)
{
    var retDict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    foreach (var dict in nestedDict)
    {
        if (typeof(TValue).IsGenericType && typeof(TValue).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>))
        {
            retDict[dict.Key] = (TValue)NestedCopy((dynamic)dict.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            retDict[dict.Key] = dict.Value;
        }
    }
    return retDict;
}
```

The more explicit code with hand-made reflection could look as follows:

```
private static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> NestedCopy<TKey, TValue>(
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue> nestedDict)
{
    var reflectionMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod("NestedCopy", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
    var retDict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    foreach (var dict in nestedDict)
    {
        if (typeof(TValue).IsGenericType && typeof(TValue).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>))
        {
            var methodToCall = reflectionMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TValue).GetGenericArguments());
            retDict[dict.Key] = (TValue)methodToCall.Invoke(null, new object[] { dict.Value });
        }
        else
        {
            retDict[dict.Key] = dict.Value;
        }
    }
    return retDict;
}
```

Note this assumes the method to belong to `Program` class and I made it static since its not using any context.

Since the decision for the `if-else` doesn't depend on `dict.Value` but only on the `TValue` that stays the same throughout the method, you could also move the condition out of the loop:

```
private static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> NestedCopy<TKey, TValue>(
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue> nestedDict)
{
    var retDict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    Func<TValue, TValue> clone;
    if (typeof(TValue).IsGenericType && typeof(TValue).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>))
    {
        clone = v => NestedCopy((dynamic)v);
    }
    else
    {
        clone = v => v;
    }
    foreach (var dict in nestedDict)
    {
        retDict[dict.Key] = clone(dict.Value);
    }
    return retDict;
}
```

Comment: Thanks...Even though half the code seems new to me.. :)

Comment: @kooldeji if it wasn't new, you wouldn't need to ask :P

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need to recursive it, it relies on you how to implement the TValue.Clone method.

```
private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> CloneDictionary<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> sourceDic)
            where TValue : ICloneable
        {
            var ret = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(sourceDic.Count, sourceDic.Comparer);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> entry in sourceDic)
            {
                ret.Add(entry.Key, (TValue)entry.Value.Clone());
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: Did I miss the point where `Dictionary<T1,T2>` started to implement the `ICloneable` interface?

Comment: It doesn’t and if it did, you could just call `Clone` on the original one.

Comment: I suggest each object need to implement the IConeable interface.

Comment: if the TValue is a reference type, retDict[dict.Key] = dict.Value; in this way not a copy !

Comment: @jerry Sure, you can suggest every object to implement `ICloneable` but this still won’t help in OP’s situation where they have nested dictionaries since you cannot just make a dictionary implement `ICloneable`…

Comment: Do you want to deep copy dictionary? if yes, retDict[dict.Key] = dict.Value; this is wrong way!